# UISearchBar like Google Places application

Tags: iphone, uisearchbar

Is it possible to customize the UISearchBar like the Google Places application on iPhone ?
Any help is welcomed ...
[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's not a UISearchBar, its a custom view with a UITextField.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible through subclassing UISearchBar and changing the subviews in `layoutSubviews` but Mark Adams is still probably right.